# Guice. Inject to static method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an utility method:

```
public static void MyUtility(ClassWhoDoesImportantThink instance, 
                             Object params...){...}
```

Usually I call this method in way:

```
public class UsualClass{
  ...
  @Inject
  ClassWhoDoesImportantThink importantInstance;
  ...
  public aMethod(){
     ...

     UtilityClass.myItility(importantInstance, arg1, arg2);
     ...
  }
}
```

Where @Inject is Guice feature.
But maybe it is exists a way to inject an "importantInstance" directly to my static utility? Smth like:

```
public static void MyUtility( Object params...){
   ClassWhoDoesImportantThink instance = 
     GuiceFeature.getObjectUsuallyInjected(ClassWhoDoesImportantThink.class);
   ... //Do job
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do this. Or at least I very strongly doubt that you can, since it isn't obvious how you would get the guice injector into `MyUtility` in a not-completely-gross way. What's wrong with the "usual" way?

Comment: @AndyTurner, I'm terrified by necessary to move this parameter from method throught methods on try to create a more complicated utility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `MyUtility`:

```
  @Inject
  static ClassWhoDoesImportantThink importantInstance;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
  static ClassWhoDoesImportantThink importantInstance;
  @Inject static void setImportantInstance(ClassWhoDoesImportantThink importantInstance) {
    MyUtility.importantInstance = importantInstance;
  }
```

And in the appropriate Guice module `configure()` method:

```
  requestStaticInjection(MyUtility.class);
```

Guice will then inject the static variable or setter during its initial setup, and `MyUtility` static methods can simply use the static field.

Comment: OP: Remember that you have to create an Injector that installs the module containing the `requestStaticInjection` for it to take effect (that's the "initial setup" alluded above) and that you're keeping mutable state in a static field. As Andy Turner mentions in the question comments, refactoring MyUtility (e.g. into a disposable, injectable class) may help keep your code clean.